# How to transparently convert absolute imports to relative inside external module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem: I need to use some external code as part of my own project. This seems to be a relatively common use case in machine learning research when trying to build new experiments on top of previously published solutions/models.

The file structure is as follows:

```
project_root/
├── external/
│   └── SomeoneElsesCode/
│       └── src/
│           └── dir1/
│               └── subdir1/
│                   ├── codeineed.py
│                   └── anciliarycode.py
└── src/
    └── MyModule/
        └── mycode.py
```

When trying to run the line

```
from external.SomeoneElsesCode.src.dir1.subdir1.codeineed import NeededClass
```

in `mycode.py` I am running into the problem with line

```
from src.dir1.subdir1.anciliarycode import AncilliaryClass
```

in `codeineed.py` since the external code is using absolute import paths. Since I do not control the code in `SomeoneElsesCode` I cannot simply adjust all import paths there. Is there any way to tell the Python interpreter to "relativize" all paths below `SomeoneElsesCode`? If not, is there any recommended way of dealing with including external code in Python projects?

Comment: You can, and probably should, submit a pull request to the owner of the broken code. In the meantime, you can fix your local version of it.

Comment: The code is not exactly broken - this is typical research code that was never intended to be treated as a library. The alternative (and unfortunately, the usual approach) is to absorb the entire codebase into my project, but that means losing the separation between the code for my paper and the code for the paper that I am citing (and also causes potential licensing issues).

Comment: In that case, just add a readme of the changes required to the external code that make it run with your project. That way you can still treat it as an external library, but with a slightly more complex install than just copy-and-paste

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have found an answer, though I hope that someone can suggest a better approach.

The solution to the problem seems to be to replace the [builtin `__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__) function with a wrapper preprocessing the path. This can be done by placing the following `__init__.py` file inside the `external` directory:

```
import builtins

default_import = builtins.__import__


class ExternalImport:
    def __init__(self, default_import) -> None:
        self.default_import = default_import

    def __call__(self, name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0):
        if (
            ("src" in name)
            and (globals is not None)
            and (hasattr(globals, "__getitem__"))
            and (globals.get("__package__", None) is not None)
            and ("external" in globals.get("__package__", ""))
        ):
            package = globals["__package__"]
            externalLib = package.replace("external.", "").split(".")[0]
            name = f"external.{externalLib}.{name}"
        return self.default_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)


builtins.__import__ = ExternalImport(default_import)
```

Essentially, I filter all import statements and look for those containing `src` and coming from the `external` module to adjust their names. This is not ideal since it requires all external packages to store their code in the `src` directory; however, I have not found any better way of detecting imports of actual packages (both built-in and installed).